# How to show data from a sub report which has multiple source

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a sub report in my main report which has a multiple source, actually 3 stored procedures. All of them have the same parameters and each brings back one row. The problem is that I can not get the data in preview. I also tried to make a PDF, but I am having the same problem, no data. Anyway, I tried also "Browse Data..." option in database fields and I can see the data there, the only place where I can see it.

Does anyone know what could be the issue? Maybe it is something with multiple sources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click on Database Fields -> Database Expert -> Tab Links, and I removed links from tables and I have preview now. So, that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create 3 subreports with one stored procedure each . There will be the same number of calls to the database , but Crystal engine will not try to figure the links between the datasources

Comment: Yes, they suggest not to use multiple sources, but I needed to make a grid of 3 rows, where each row is a result of each procedure, no links needed. But they were set, so I removed them and everything is ok. Thanks for the answer.